# Simulation Speed of Nonlinear Solver in Modelica

Tags: performance, simulation, modelica

Why does Modelica's nonlinear solver `Modelica.Math.Nonlinear.solveOneNonlinearEquation` take more time to solve a nonlinear equation than traditional fixed point iterative (FPI) scheme?
The equation

```
y= arctan(1-x/1+x)-x
```

solved by the `solveOneNonlinearEquation` solver (which basically uses Brent's Method) solves the above equation in 6 iterations whereas traditional iterative approach takes 111 iterations. However, the CPU time taken by the iterative scheme is lesser than that taken by the `solveOneNonlinearEquation` solver (see image).

Why is this? Could be due to computational efficiency of the iterative scheme i.e., to say lesser event generation in the iterative scheme?

[image: CPU Time of nonlinear equation solved by Brent's method (solveOneNonlinearEquation solver) and typical fixed point iterative (FPI) scheme]

Comment: I guess you mean `Modelica.Math.Nonlinear.solveOneNonlinearEquation` with `oneSolveNonlinearEquation`, right?

Comment: Yes it basically uses Brent's method

Answer (score 6):

The different root finding methods have different properties. Convergence speed is just one, and it can be counted in number of iterations, or in CPU time. Both will greatly depend on start values, curvature and monotonicity of the function, bounds, cost to evaluate the function, availability of analytic derivatives etc.. Other interesting properties could be guarantee of convergence, or whether derivatives are required.
The Wikipedia article on root finding algorithms gives a good overview of the advantages and disadvantages of the different methods:

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root-finding_algorithm

If one method works much better than others for your special case, you should just implement and use it! Be careful when benchmarking, it is very easy to find examples where each method can shine. For this reason, you should test each algorithm on a variety of functions, maybe 10 different ones, and each one with different intervals. Bisection will perform worse for the same function but larger start interval. Brent is a good and proven method, that is why it is used in the MSL. You could even think about sending a Pull Request to the MSL and add alternatives.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. While I understand that convergence speed depends on many parameters like start values, curvature, monotonicity etc., what is perplexing to me is that the solver does 111 iterations in less CPU time than just 6 iterations. Although the 111 iterations is a basic while loop that evaluates the equation for different values. The Brent's method also is basically a while loop but takes more time although the solver has to compute just 6 iterations. Any reason why? Could this have something to do with the way Modelica treats the two iterative schemes?

Comment: Brent constructs a quadratic approximation of your function and solves that. I am not sure how expensive that is, but I would have expected that to be in the same order of magnitude as evaluating arctan(). I do not exactly know what you compared, and how you did it, obviously you implemented some root finding function yourself.

Comment: To understand whether it is a problem with the implementation, the algorithm in general, just a very special example, you could do the same comparison in a different language, e.g. python, where you have both algorithms readily available; or you could just use a different example (e.g. try a square function, Brent should be able to solve it in 1 step), or introduce some timers, or print statements to see what branch Brent is using.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I will definitely check the computability of Python in solving the non linear equation using Brents and FPI schemes to see which is more efficient. However, I'm facing a problem that sometimes the Brent's method(oneSolve) does not converge below the set tolerance but Modelica still outputs the result. Suppose I set a tolerance convergence criteria of 1e-8, Brent doesnt solve the equations until the set tolerance is reached and maybe stops at 1e-7. Any idea what the reason for this could be? Could it be that the function diverges after the 1e-7 tolerance is reached?

Comment: The stop criterion is 
      `if abs(m) <= tol or fb == 0.0 then
      // root found (interval is small enough)
      found := true;`
 So for debugging, just print out tol and fb and see why Brent has stopped.

Comment: Turning on optimization for the C compiler (/O2 option) may have an impact, also with regards to the relative performance.

Comment: On printing fb and abs(m), I find that there is a possibility of Brent's loop ending because abs(m) < tol. However, the value of fb is very far from zero. In such a case, why does Brent give a result as though it converged? Isnt the point of Brent to find the value of u such that f(u) or f(b) in this case should be as close to zero say below 1e-8 tolerance?

Comment: Maybe the x values reached very close to each other but still the y value is no where close to zero. Does this mean Brent failed to converge?